# How can I pay my USA's Green Card fee from Pakistan before leaving?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I live in Pakistan and I have got immigrant visa to USA and I want to submit Green Card fee before leaving to USA.

[This](https://public-prod-elis2.uscis.dhs.gov/efile/app/app/iv/#!/) is the link where I have to submit fee.

After entering required information, there are only 2 options,

**Pay Via Bank Account (ACH)** and **Pay Via Plastic Card (PC) (ex: American Express, Discover, Mastercard, VISA)**

Now my question is, how can I submit fee from here? I have bank account in Pakistan and *VISA Debit cards* but I don't think I can pay using them.

**EDIT:**
[Here](http://www.thedesidesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Allied-Bank-Cash-Shop.jpg) is a sample debit card, I have same one.

Comment: Why wouldn't your visa card work for the pay by card option? Did you try it? What happened? Any errors?

Comment: Debit cards can do almost anything credit cards can do.  Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @LorenPechtel see the edits ... I have shown sample of a debit card I have.

and I get "The card has been declined, the transaction will not be processed." error after entering my information.

Comment: @Gagravarr I get "The card has been declined, the transaction will not be processed." error

Comment: Did you check with your bank? They might be blocking it thinking it's potential fraud

Comment: @Gagravarr i dont know how do i check

Comment: Ring them up? Walking into the branch and ask? Check online? Send them a secure message online? It'll all depend on your bank, that's not something we can tell you!

Answer (score 1):

[Your bank](https://www.abl.com/personal-banking/credit-debit-cards/allied-cashshop-visa-debit-card/) claims that this is a Visa Debit card (not a Visa Electron, which can only be used at ATMs in the US, not for purchases).

So this card should work.

The problem is most likely that, because the charge to the card is coming from the United States, that your bank has blocked it for being an unexpected foreign transaction.

The solution is to contact your bank and inform them that you are trying to use the card to make a purchase from the United States. You can call them at 0800-22522. They should then be able to allow the card to make the foreign purchase.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will talk to bank and will let you know.